# Just Audio Background Media player doesn't show buttons

Tags: flutter, just-audio, audio-service

Added Just Audio Background functionality to Just Audio Playlist example and I could see player to run fine in the background but previous / play / pause / next buttons aren't visible. Although, I could virtually press and functionality works as expected, just that they are not visible.
Attached is the image for reference:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YACbl.png)

I'm using MediaItem referrenced from Background library and assigning metadata to those as follows

```
AudioSource.uri(
  Uri.parse(
      "https://s3.amazonaws.com/scifri-episodes/scifri20181123-episode.mp3"),
  tag: MediaItem(
    id: '1',
    artist: "Science Friday",
    title: "A Salute To Head-Scratching Science",
    artUri: Uri.parse(
        "https://media.wnyc.org/i/1400/1400/l/80/1/ScienceFriday_WNYCStudios_1400.jpg"),
  ),
)
```

Rest everything is same as listed in JustAudioPlaylist example in the following Github link:
https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/blob/minor/just_audio/example/lib/example_playlist.dart

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you find a solution for this?